# The Tools used on this cane?

Tags: tool-selection, tool-identification, wood-identification

[image]

What were the tools used to achieve what was done here? Namely the stripping off of all the bark that used to be over the white-ish parts. Note that the top portion is smooth and sort of transitions into a gradient that seems like it was carved by hand? I also would like to know how the bark was stripped away from the scarred wood so cleanly, I would assume this was not done by hand but I'm no good at this.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[image]

As shown on the picture: the flats in the lower area look like what you get when you whittle with (probably) a knife. I would imagine the whole thing was shaped with a knife before the smoother top area was hand-sanded.

If the bark was removed when the wood was green the maker probably just scraped it off with the backside of a knife. I think this is most likely due the the ragged transition between the bark and the wood. Or it could have been peeled/cut off when the wood was dry. It's not hard to do since the bark is much softer than the wood.

I would be surprised if any power tools were used.

Edit: For the transitions between wood and bark I would score a line with a knife, cutting down to the wood. Then I'd scrape/cut/peel back the bark away from the cut line. Again, this is not hard because the bark is so much softer than the wood. It also looks like the maker followed lines and ridges already in the bark.

Comment: How about the upper portion of the spot in the photo where the bark that is still there is very uniform, was that also a knife?

Comment: Do you mean an the top of the cane? I'd imagine it was done with a knife but I'm having a hard time understanding what's going on up there. An oblique picture from the top of the cane would help.

Comment: Added another picture to the top to better illustrate what I'm talking about. I had a perfect picture but it's like 0.01 over 2mb. Thanks, Stackexchange. Specifically the area around the secondary branch, how the bark was cut and formed 'kind of' like a triangle. How they made the transition so abrupt from bark to the underwood.

Comment: Ah I see, I'll edit the main post.

Comment: Thank you Jambo, all of the ways you suggested helped finish this project. The cane even looks consistent to the work I didn't personally do.

Comment: @Jambo - Open the picture in `Paint`, then `Save As` and select `.PNG`. Those are quite small yet still pretty good quality. _Assumes running Windows - there are probably similar Mac options. Linux? Use the GIMP_